# Wordpress custom plugin not shown in roles except admin

Tags: wordpress, user-roles

I wrote a custom wordpress plugin that is shown in the left menu bar in the backend of WP.

My problem is, that it is just shown if I log in as an administrator. If the editor logs in he can't see it. Is there any way that I can enable it so that every role can see it?

I tried to google the problem but didn't get any satisfying results, that's why I am asking it here.

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: What plugin is it? a link perhaps?

Comment: I wrote the whole plugin myself.

Comment: Like a boss! In most plugins I find an `if(!is_admin()){` there's probably one in your admin files too, try to find and modify it.

Comment: hehe, thanks! I will look into it in a minute. Meanwhile a found a plugin called Advanced Access Manager which seems to have this option and much more..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the proper capability, third parameter in the add_option_page() function which you would have used to create the menu.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page