# Wordpress - Access to single plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles, capability

I need to allow editor (role) to use "WP All Export" plugin.
I`m trying to solve my problem using this code:

```
add_options_page('WP All Export Pro', 'All Export', 'edit_posts', 'pmxe-admin-manage', 'wp-all-export-pro_options');
```

But its not working for me... 
I'm a newbie in WP so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030123/wordpress-custom-plugin-not-shown-in-roles-except-admin?rq=1),

> You need to set the proper capability, **third parameter** in the add_option_page() function which you would have used to create the menu.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page

So, what you need to do is set the correct capability.

I think that capability is: 'manage_options'.  (Look at line 145 [here](https://github.com/soflyy/wp-all-export/blob/master/wp-all-export.php))

But maybe it is pmxe-manage-options?

The plugin registers the options page only when the user has that capability.

Answer (score 2):

Try install this wordpress plugin. hope it help your solve your problem without coding it urself
https://wpfront.com/user-role-editor-pro/

purchase a license of this https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/ allow you to add extra capabilities. You can even change naming of your admin menus/submenus many extra features :) I can only tell you its totally worth it